# Do I need a facebook app to build a like / share button?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I am including a facebook Like/Share button on my webpage.
I don't need anything more fancy than that, but the code still requires an app id.
(I am using the "url" option from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/#settings)

Do I need to build a Facebook app just to include a like button on a page? And can this facebook app be in sandbox mode if I want to use the ID?

My code:

```
    <iframe width="400" height="40" frameborder="0"
     src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?
    href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.nl&width=400&layout=standard
 &action=like&show_faces=false&locale=nl_NL&share=true
&height=35&appId=MYAPPIDHERE"></iframe>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635196/do-facebook-like-buttons-require-an-app-id

Comment: Thanks, I missed that - so it seems you can just manually delete the app id code from the button.

It remains confusing though, there's no clear explanation of why facebook puts an app id in all the "like" code - and what happens if you manually remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember that app id was obligatory for like buttons early. I suppose now it required to get more complex statistic on this button, but not sure. With application in sandbox this button definitly will work, I try to do it with my app. Also as expirement just try to insert like button code with out appId=MYAPPIDHERE parameter. I suppose it should also work (you can see if you missed something in its functionality with parameter and without it).